# Filter Airbnb rooms for Eiffel tower view

Tags: france, accommodation, paris, airbnb, local-knowledge

I am looking for a room with Eiffel tower view. I can't seem to find any relevant filter (which I understand is too specific, but on the other hand too iconic to ignore).

Any ideas how to approach this?

I thought about filtering rooms' descriptions by the phrase "Eiffel tower view" or so, but such functionality seems absent.

I also thought about marking the area close to the tower, but this feels like an overkill, because 1) the tower is so tall, so I don't need to have a super close room to the tower to have its view I guess, and 2) the views depend on the direction of the balcony/window(s). I also Yahoo'ed on how to, and got articles on top 10 Airbnb rooms in Paris with Eiffel tower view, but they are too expensive for me.

Comment: Given that the Eiffel tower is probably *the* iconic landmark in Paris, there is going to be a lot of demand for accommodation with views of it.  As such, I'd expect the price to be a lot higher than other locations which don't have a view.  As an analogy, I've seen $10k per night prices for AirBnB's in Texas for the day of the full eclipse in April 2024.

Comment: @PeterM You can find properties under <150€/night with pretty nice views of the Eiffel Tower, which, given the usual prices in Paris, really isn't that much.

Comment: There may well be a lot of demand, but there is also a lot of supply! As the Eiffel Tower is so tall and prominent (and the terrain is mostly either flat or sloping towards it), I would guesstimate that about 10% of the apartments in Paris have a view on it...

Comment: Op: you should specify what you consider to be too expensive. Different people have different attitudes about how expensive things are.

Comment: @PeterM. - I would check that. You can find places renting for USD 10,000 per night in Texas at *any* time of the year. Since it is, I think, the maximum price that one can set, some people set their rental property at that price to deter anyone from booking it during a period that they want to have it open. I have personally communicated with someone who did that. There are also fake listings, which naturally also will be set at the maximum price, because after all, the scammers can always negotiate the price down, but would prefer to have the option to scam for the maximum amount.

Comment: All the ones at that price level in Dallas seem to be from the same company, and I guarantee that they are not *really* renting out a one-bedroom apartment for 10,000 per night. Maybe it's some kind of [tax dodge to get rid of their assets](https://skift.com/2022/07/16/shuttered-property-manager-wanderjaunt-is-trying-to-sell-its-assets/amp/).

Comment: @IliaSmilga i would think that to be a pretty high estimate. Remember that a lot of Paris proper has buildings all of the same height (usually 6 to 8 floors), which makes it unlikely to have a view at all from most places. Even when there is a view, it still needs to point in the right direction.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, as per the Greek philosopher Protagoras, everything is relative, so I'd consider expensive everything going much of the average price of the rooms with Eiffel tower view. However this is something I'll select when I get a list of most/all the rooms with a view; the question is how to get them, not which one to select.

Comment: @Obie2.0 For the places in Texas I looked, that are on the path of the eclipse, there is a huge price spike on the day of the eclipse compared to the previous and following days.  Yes it could be a booking/reservation method - but AirBnb hosts have the ability to block off dates, and there are also people who chase eclipses globally and are willing to pay for it.  I also saw price spikes for general hotels as well.  My solution is to stay 1 Hr away from the max eclipse cone, and drive to a suitable location in the day.

Comment: Notions of what constitutes an "Eiffel Tower view" will vary, e.g. a glimpse of the top if you lean over the balcony, vs a full view from inside the property. There is no standard definition so just searching for text won't work, you'll need to find a photo and trust that it's genuine and not misleading.

Comment: @StuartF yes of course, but text will lead me to the listings with that view, and I can choose between them, depending on how good does the view actually look (based on the photographs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cannot guarantee that it will always be accurate or exhaustive, but using a generic search engine and restricting results to airbnb.com [seems to yield promising results](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aairbnb.com+Eiffel+tower+view). The link points to Google but including “site:airbnb.com” in the search query should work with all search engines (I also tried Duckduckgo and Kagi, which is my go-to search engine). Indeed, it seems it works even on yahoo.com (which serves Bing search results I think).

The key is to use the ”site:” prefix to restrict the search based on the URL instead of simply the word “airbnb”. You can combine it with other keywords, e.g.

> Eiffel tower view site:airbnb.com

With such a specific search query, you don't even need to specify “room” or “Paris” to get direct links to specific listings. One drawback is that it won't filter by availability or any other criteria, you have to check each result manually afterwards.

Another idea is to check another site like VRBO, Booking.com, or Expedia and see if their search feature works better for you. The days where most properties on AirBnB were genuine spare rooms from individuals with one or two listings and Booking only covered hotels are long gone, especially in a city like Paris. All these sites are competing with each other to include as much inventory as possible and I would expect quite a bit of overlap.

Comment: +1, though adding the search term "Paris" might still be a good idea. That *seems* to be the OP's intended destination... though they only mention that at the very end, so they might want to exclude [the other one](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=las+vegas+eiffel+tower) from their search results.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I didn't even think of Las Vegas, good point, tnx for all the help!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the "Amazing views" feature search (in the top bar, not in the filters) to eliminate all that don't have a view at all.

You definitely **won't have only** rooms with a view on the Eiffel Tower (there are views on the Sacré Coeur and other generic views), but it does filter out a lot of stuff and if you can see the Eiffel Tower from that property, they surely will make it visible on the first photo (though sometimes it's that tiny thing miles away!).

(Edit: I stand corrected, some people are weird enough to NOT make it obvious on the first photo!)

Depending on your filters sometimes you get a lot of Eiffel Tower hits right at the start, sometimes you have to scroll down quite a bit through results.

The advantage though, is that you can still use your other filters (property type, rooms, beds, price, amenities...).

Small example of a lucky result:

[image]

You can also use your browser's "Find" feature to search in the results on each page but sometimes the "Eiffel" word will be cut off in the title.